# Bokeh widgets CSS

Tags: python, css, bokeh

I've found the following problem when working with Bokeh (0.12.4):
When I set the width of a 'Select' element in such a way that it can not
display its contents in full anymore Bokeh will adapt the size.

This tends to break the layout I have in mind (mind you, I'm not really good
at this).
My current 'workaround' is to actually define the following HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans);
            body {
              font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
              -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
              text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
              color: #fff;
              background: #2F2F2F;
             }

            .selector select{
                width: 97%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bokeh Crossfilter Example</title>
        {{ bokeh_css }}
        {{ bokeh_js }}
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
        {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
    </body>
</html>
```

(N.B. this is adapted from Bokeh examples) and to hard-code the css class in 
the script because, apparently, Bokeh does not accept the same setting, if it is provided through
theme.yaml

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import Select
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure

def plot_placeholder():
    p = figure( tools='pan,box_zoom,reset',responsive=True);
    return p

############################################
#options
Data = ['Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious', 'dumb', 'example']
sel = Select(title='Option 1', value = 'None', options = ['None'] + Data, name='OptionSelector', css_classes=['selector'])

#############################################################################
layout = row([sel, plot_placeholder()], sizing_mode='fixed', width=400)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "Statistical Plots"
```

This works, but I'm wondering whether one could do this with a Python-only
implementation.
E.g. I'd like to know whether one could do without defining a template AND
forcing the properties unto all selectors.

Furthermore, as an extension to this problem, how could I pass a CSS file to Bokeh without resorting to templates. I've tried CSSResources, but did not get anywhere, for whilst it will yield a list of CSS files the list does not appear to be mutable.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your last question you can have a layout something like this:
(For simplicity i just have styles.css in the same directory as index.html, but you could put that in say static/css/styles.css if you wish).

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title> Title here </title>
            {{ bokeh_css }}
            {{ bokeh_js }}
            <style>      
                {% include 'styles.css' %}
            </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. My goal is a Bokeh app which requires only a minimum of work outside python (preferably none).

Comment: I will take a look at trying to set those values within python and let you know if i can find a solution later.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a similar answer and I found out below solution. You can define `Div` which includes style and add it to `curdoc()`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import Select
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure

def plot_placeholder():
    p = figure( tools='pan,box_zoom,reset',responsive=True);
    return p

############################################
#options
Data = ['Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious', 'dumb', 'example']
sel = Select(title='Option 1', value = 'None', options = ['None'] + Data, name='OptionSelector', css_classes=['selector'])

style = Div(text="""
<style>
            @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans);
            body {
              font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
              -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
              text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
              color: #fff;
              background: #2F2F2F;
             }

            .selector select{
                width: 97%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
</style>
""")


#############################################################################
layout = row([sel, plot_placeholder(), style], sizing_mode='fixed', width=400)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "Statistical Plots"
```